# Parse out Excel File with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure on a MSSQL Server 2008 R2 box. This stored procedure picks up an excel file and parses it out and inserts the values into the database.

This works great when I run the stored procedure from SSMS on that server. However, when I try and call that stored procedure from my application in the browser, I get the following error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The OLE DB
>   provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the
>   error.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work in the browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly a permission problem: the user impersonated by your connection either cannot access the file or has no openrowset permissions

Comment: Thanks. This gave me a direction. My users could not access the file.

Comment: I'm glad the hint helped, please mark the answer as correct when it works